# Read Data After postchange() from Custom Query View Object Adf Business Compontent

Tags: java, oracle-adf

There is An issue when reading an attribute which is updated from Entity as following :
`entity.setXXX(123);`

I read The Column (XXX) in View Object from Custom query but the column is empty, but when reading it from entity view it's reflected even after it I postchange values as following :

`getApplicationModule().getTransaction().postChanges();`

Note: Requirement needs to read before commit.